# getting error -> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. while running a react native web project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I am trying to run a react-native-web project, when I try running it, I get the following error

[image]

When I stacktraced I found my error is exactly happening in the following code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import qs from 'qs';
import {Images} from '../../assets';
import {API} from '../../api';
import {disabledColor, successColor} from '../../config/colors';
    export default function LoginScreenWeb(props) {
      const {navigation} = props;
      const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
      const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
      const [width, getWidth] = useState(null);
      const SetWidth = () => {
        getWidth(window.screen.availWidth);
      };
    
      // useEffect(() => {
      //   // SetWidth();
      //   // setInterval(SetWidth, 1000);
      // }, []);
    
      // const onHandlePress = () => {
      //   async function post() {
      //     try {
      //       const response = await API.postFormData(
      //         `/users/signup`,
      //         qs.stringify({
      //           firstName,
      //           mobile,
      //         }),
      //       );
      //       navigation.navigate('otp');
      //       localStorage.setItem('mobile', mobile);
      //       console.log('loginRes--', response);
      //     } catch (e) {
      //       console.log(e);
      //     }
      //   }
      //   post();
      // };
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <View
            // style={
            //   width > 414 ? styles.inner_container_web : styles.inner_container_mob
            // }
            >
            <Image
              source={Images.login_web}
              // style={width > 414 ? styles.image_web : styles.image_mob}
            />
            <KeyboardAvoidingView>
              <View style={{padding: 16}}>
                <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Name</Text>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Enter your name"
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  // value={firstName}
                  // onChangeText={(firstName) =>
                  //   setFirstName(firstName.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''))
                  // }
                />
                <Text style={styles.textLabel}>+91</Text>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  maxLength={10}
                  keyboardType="number-pad"
                  // value={mobile}
                  // onChangeText={(mobile) =>
                  //   setMobile(mobile.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
                  // }
                />
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  {/* {firstName && mobile.length === 10 ? ( */}
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      // onPress={() => onHandlePress()}
                      style={styles.enable_continue}>
                      <Text style={styles.continue}>Continue</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  {/* ) : ( */}
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.disble_continue}>
                      <Text style={styles.continue}>Continue</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  {/* )} */}
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <View style={styles.cookies} />
                  <Text style={{fontSize: '12px'}}>
                    By continuing you agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy
                    policy
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
```

As soon as I uncomment the useeffect part I get the  Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. error however I am using a functional component here.

Am unable to figure how to fix the error, could anyone help me out here, thanks in advance, let me know if anything else is required for clarity

Stacktrace ->
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any hook imports here and I wouldn't suggest copying all your source code (minmal, complete example). However, there's more to the stack trace that's not shown in your screenshot. I suggest looking at the stack trace to find which component triggered the error.

Comment: This often happens when we use the react hooks outside the component.

Comment: @stealththeninja I have edited te question could you please check

Comment: add your imports of LoginScreenWeb to question. sometime it can be import error

Comment: @AakashRajni added

Comment: Great updates! It's a shot in the dark but does splitting the function declaration and export have a different outcome? `function LoginScreenWeb () { ... } export default LoginScreenWeb;`

Answer (score 0):

try this too :

```
const LoginScreenWeb= (props) => {//////another code}
export default LoginScreenWeb
```

Also check the version(react) you are working with..
React Hooks are available in **React 16.8**

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This was an error of npm link and version mismatch, once I linked my react package the error got fixed